# Search and replace in Xcode

Tags: html, regex, xcode

I have the following string in several places throughout a massive HTML file: `<div class="author">Some Author's Name</div>`.  I want to replace that with `<author>Some Author's Name</author>` and obviously adjust the corresponding CSS classes.

Is it possible to do that in a single Find and Replace in Xcode 6.1 without having to go through line by line?

Comment: Use vi :sn,$/old/new/

Comment: @wshcdr the OP says `do that in a single Find and Replace in Xcode 6.1` not in VI, furthermore, he'll need to play with regex if we want to keep the author's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you this article [replace with regex in XCode](http://roadfiresoftware.com/2013/12/replacing-regular-expressions-in-an-xcode-project/).

Use the regex `<div class="author">(.*)</div>` to find your entities and replace with `<author>$1 </author>`

Comment: Okay, this is what I was expecting, but I am running into the problem that the author's name is being replaced by a "1" rather than being retained.  I have double checked that both find and replace terms are correct.

Comment: Interestingly, previously the find term was finding results, but now with the added `\]` it is returning no results.

Comment: @rkent Make sure you select `Replace > Regular Expression` in the Find Navigator

Comment: I have selected Regular Expression, and to ensure I was not doing something wrong, I copied and pasted the expressions.  Without the `\]` it is giving me many results as expected, but with it I get a no results message.

Comment: @rkent I don't have XCode right now, I'll test in this evening. I made a mistake about the `\]`, it should not be there

Comment: @rkent I edited the answer. Xcode uses `$1` instead of `\1` for capturing groups.

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis erf, my sources are bad then ! Thanks Guillaume !